# Python: Variable not defined in external class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code. Although, the problem is very simple but I cannot figure out the reason behind it.

The following is my main.py:

```
from model_MNIST import Model

def main():
    model = Model()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the model_MNIST.py file is as follows:

```
# some import statements
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, input_dimensions, output_dimensions):
        # some init statements

    def train_on_data(self, training_data, training_labels):
        N = training_labels.size
```

Whenever the class initialization is called I get an output as **name 'training_labels' is not defined.** This is preventing the execution of the program. Can someone point me out what I might be missing?

Edit1: Please refer to the shared link for the file. [SharedFolder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r8Vbu24J-AZ12tPfUxJ3E_kE7PFE6KNs)

Comment: Please edit your question to include your actual code, and the full error traceback output.

Comment: Which line is the error actually occurring? where is train_on_data() being invoked?

Comment: I have provided the shared links for the files. The error comes as soon as the class is instantiated.

Comment: Your code as posted in the above question does not match the code in the shared folder that you link to. Please update the question with the real code.

Comment: @quamrana the code from both of the files would take up a lot of space, that is why I gave a general scenario of my code. I do not think it would be problem to refer to the shared link.

Comment: The idea behind stackoverflow is that it should be self contained and when anyone in the future finds this question, they should be able to see all the necessary code here and not have to battle with links that are long dead.

Comment: btw you have indentation problems. Do you know about indentation in python?

Comment: @quamrana Does it show you indentation issue, cause it does not show any indentation error to me. No offense, but I know what an indent means in python. Moreover, I have resolved all the indentations I think so.

Comment: Ok, you obviously do know about indentation from your previous questions. See my answer.

Comment: @quamrana I'll update the above code with the real issue. Thanks for the attention though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172856/discussion-between-rishik-mani-and-quamrana).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a summary of the code from your link:

```
# some import statements
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, input_dimensions, output_dimensions):
        # some init statements

    def train_on_data(self, training_data, training_labels):
        '''
        Multiline comment
        '''
    N = training_labels.size
    ...
```

In the above code the last line is part of the class, not the `train_on_data` method.

I think the last line (and the others elided) should be indented to be part of that method.

Comment: Bingo. Code in this method from this statement onward was not indented properly. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

From the shared code, what I can understand that you have confused with **class and instance variables**.

In the function `train_on_data`, you have some codes like `self.training_labels = training_labels` but your `init` method doesn't contain the `self.training_labels` variable.

Comment: Ah thank you for pointing out that. I'll correct the nonsense mistake and then check if it works. I'll update then.

Comment: @mb0850: In python is doesn't matter whether instance variables are initialised in init if they are initialised in another method. (As to whether this is good programming or not is another question).

Comment: @quamrana That is true, however, in the shared code self.training_data is being defined inside a method(train_on_data), so if there is an invocation of that variable in any other method without running train_on_data first, it would give error

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this `Model.train_on_data(X_train, y_train)` to  `model.train_on_data(X_train, y_train)` in main_MNIST.py, in simple .py file https://pastebin.com/JZArvWC3

Comment: Yeah already tried that. I think what @mb0850 posted as solution might be the real reason here. I'll update.